# Python Error - Type: <class 'AttributeError'> Args: ("'module' object has no attribute 'Retry'",)

Tags: python, attributeerror

I have the same Python script in two environments. In one it works fine but in the other I get this error in my logs:

```
15-May-2017 15:29:39  |  Type: <class 'AttributeError'>
15-May-2017 15:29:39  |  Args: ("'module' object has no attribute 'Retry'",)
```

I think it comes from the following:

```
import minio
import logging
from io import BytesIO
from minio import Minio


#============================================
# todo - error handling in all routines
#============================================

class SoftLayerUtils:

    @staticmethod
    def getClient(args):
        client = Minio(
            args.billing_storage_endpoint,
            access_key=args.storage_accesskey,
            secret_key=args.storage_secretkey,
            secure=False
        )

        return client
```

Unfortunately the error doesn't tell me very much so I don't really know where to go with it.

Does anybody have any advice or can you see an issue with the code?

```
16-May-2017 07:33:23  |  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
16-May-2017 07:33:23  |  Initialising get_usage
16-May-2017 07:33:23  |  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
16-May-2017 07:33:23  |  net = testnet
16-May-2017 07:33:23  |  manager_url = https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/manager/api/json/1.0/list.adm
16-May-2017 07:33:23  |  storage_endpoint = endpoint_url
16-May-2017 07:33:23  |  storage_bucket = bucket_url
16-May-2017 07:33:23  |  Calling https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/manager/api/json/1.0/list.adm
16-May-2017 07:33:23  |  [GET] -> https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/manager/api/json/1.0/list.adm
16-May-2017 07:33:23  |  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
16-May-2017 07:33:23  |  https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 "GET /manager/api/json/1.0/list.adm HTTP/1.1" 200 1473
16-May-2017 07:33:23  |     |- OK
16-May-2017 07:33:23  |  Type: <class 'AttributeError'>
16-May-2017 07:33:23  |  Args: ("'module' object has no attribute 'Retry'",)
16-May-2017 07:33:23  |  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
16-May-2017 07:33:23  |  Finished
16-May-2017 07:33:23  |  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
16-May-2017 07:33:23  |  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
16-May-2017 07:33:23  |  Uploading file /opt/billing/bin/get_usage/get-usage.debug
16-May-2017 07:33:23  |  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
16-May-2017 07:33:23  |  Type: <class 'AttributeError'>
16-May-2017 07:33:23  |  Args: ("'module' object has no attribute 'Retry'",)
```

As a little further testing, if I do the following in Pyhon:

```
>>> import minio
>>> from minio import Minio
>>> Minio("url", "access_key", "secret_key", False)
```

I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/minio/api.py", line 152, in __init__
    retries=urllib3.Retry(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Retry'
```

If however I use boto3:

```
>>> import boto3
>>> s3client = boto3.client('s3', endpoint_url='https://url',
        aws_access_key_id = 'access_key',
        aws_secret_access_key = 'secret_key')
    print(s3client.list_buckets())
```

I get a json response.

It looks like one package works and the other doesn't.

Comment: post the full stacktrace please

Comment: Sorry, I'm not used to Python. How do I do that?

Comment: You would have been staring at the full stack trace (which gave all the lines in the current execution stack when the error occurred) but only copy pasted a bit of it

Comment: OK, I added it to the original query. It doesn't tell very much though.

Comment: sorry this is not a stacktrace. It maybe in your log file.

Comment: Yes, this is my log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This resolved the issue:

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade urllib3
```

I was on:

```
pip3 show urllib3
---
Name: urllib3
Version: 1.7.1
Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Requires:
```

I'm now on:

```
pip3 show urllib3
---
Name: urllib3
Version: 1.21.1
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
Requires:
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between the `minio` and `urllib3` modules.  Either `urllib3` is outdated on the machine that shows the problem, or you've got a `urllib3.py` file floating around that isn't the actual module.

Comment: pip3 show urllib3
---
Name: urllib3
Version: 1.7.1
Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Requires:

that's what I have on the server. I've minio 2.2.2